# How do I get the content of the internal server (500) error?

Tags: c#, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I want to get the content of the 500 error: neither appears to let me do so, exceptions are thrown:

```
using(var wc = new WebClient()){
    wc.DownloadString(address).Dump();
}
using(var wc = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = await wc.GetStringAsync(address);
    result.Dump();
}
```

and yes address is a valid address `"http://foo.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login"`
and I have tried them each individually.

How do I read the content/response of the 500 error from the asp.net site?

Comment: What do you mean by "neither appears to let me do so"? what have you tried to do?

Comment: The method DownloadString returns a String, can't you just put that in a variable?

Comment: @Mez Looks like he's using LinqPad; it's a very useful tool for running code snippets to experiment with a bit of code.

Comment: @Mez not when it is an exception that isn't being caught, I imagine the proposed answer is correct, need to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `WebException` has a `Response` property. It works like any other response. You can read its contents and the exact status code.

Comment: is there a non try-catch option for doing this?

Comment: With WebClient, no. I wish there was. I don't know for HttpClient.

Answer (score 2):

This shows the rest of the details of how you might read the `Response` property [usr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24142501/57883) referred to

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {           
        using(var wc = new WebClient()){
            wc.DownloadString(Util.ReadLine("sitename?")).Dump("success");
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        string response;
        using(var stream=ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        using(var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            response=sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        response.Dump("error");
    }

}
```

Comment: @jgauffin idk, haven't spent time on meta to figure out which is most appropriate.

Comment: ShareAlike license allows anyone to make improvements of existing answers. Easier for other readers.